# How do I change the JSON stream I get back from Fetch using Deno?

Tags: deno

I am new to Deno and have the following simple code...

```
const getCOP = async()=>{
    const resp = await fetch("....", {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        apiKey
      },
    });

    return await resp.body;
}
let resp = {}
return new Response(resp.body, {
        status: resp.status,
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        },
});
resp.body = await getCOP();
resp.status = 200;
```

It returns

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1675621083,
    "base": "COP",
    "date": "2023-02-05",
    "rates": {
        "EUR": 0.000199,
        "GBP": 0.000179,
        "USD": 0.000216
    }
}
```

What I would like to do would be the equivalent of this in normal JS...

```
return {
  rate : resp.body.rates,
  copPerDollar : 1 / resp.body.rates.USD
}
```

Of course this doesn't seem to work because instead of an actual json obj it is a readable stream. How do I transform this stream into a json object and then restream it to the body of the sent request?

Comment: The code you've shown will not compile and throws a `SyntaxError` at runtime (top level `return`). Can you update the question to include a [mre]? Additionally: why not just return the [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) itself from the `getCOP` function instead of only its stream body, — so that you can later use the built-in [json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) body parser (first [cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone) it if necessary)?

Comment: Alternatively: if you've provided a contrived example just to illustrate a case for converting a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) representing a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) payload into a JS native parsed representation of that JSON, then will you please update the question to clarify the root question?